# Displaying data inside textarea (ejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to get data (taken from mongo) to display into a textarea.
It's purpose is so that I can edit data within the database without actually touching the database itself. 
I can display the data within normal HTML tags but I'm pretty clueless on how to get it to display it within a textarea (or any other tags that allow me to edit and re-submit the new data)

I'm rendering with EJS, and so far, everything display correctly with

```
<%= text %>
```

I just need it to work within a editable text area

Comment: Please show what you have so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
<textarea id="yourTextArea"><%= text %></textarea>
```